# How to send null value to database table column if the time field is empty?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using mssql, here time field is not mandatory field.So that while user try to submit the form, column need to add NULL. If i trying to add 0:00 sql server is taking 12:00 AM.Instead of that i need to add NULL value or blank column.If time field is not empty then am converting time to 24hours format.If user type blank space in time field add NULL to database.

AJAX

```
$('#newModalFormJob').validate({
      rules: {
        Start_Time: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        Start_Time: {
          required: "Required"
        }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {

        var End_Time_convert = $("#End_Time").val();
        if ($("#End_Time").val() == ""){
            var End_Time = $('#End_Time').val("");
        }
        else{
            var End_Time = timeconvert(End_Time_convert);
        }
        var contractID = $('#contractID').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'savejob',
          data: {
            getEnd_Time: End_Time,                
          },
          success: function(data) {

           //console.log(data);
          } 
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like this?

```
        $data = array(
            .....
            'Start_time' => $this->input->post('getStart_Time') ?: null,
            'end_time' => $this->input->post('getEnd_Time') ?: null,
            .....
        );
```

And in your jQuery, you can do:

```
var End_Time_convert = $("#End_Time").val();
if ($("#End_Time").val() == ""){
    var End_Time = "";
}
else{
    var End_Time = timeconvert(End_Time_convert);
}
```

Comment: what i need to do here in jquery??if ($("#End_Time").val() == ""){
            var End_Time = $('#End_Time').val("");
        }
        else{
            var End_Time = timeconvert(End_Time_convert);
        }

Comment: You can do this in jquery:
`if ($("#End_Time").val() == ""){ var End_Time = ""; } else{ var End_Time = timeconvert(End_Time_convert); }`

Comment: when i alert variable end_time if the field is empty,its showing [object object]

Comment: If you want to accept empty string on the PHP side, then you just set the `End_Time` to empty string in jquery :)

Hope you get what i mean?